# Force the C compiler not to inline an entry from an array

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers, inlining

I have an array of C function pointers:

```
int f1 (void) {
    return 1;
}
int f2 (void) {
    return 2;
}
int (*const functions[])(void) = {f1, f2};
```

Somewhere else in the code (using a third party tool), I destroy the content of the functions array, before using it. 
Therefore,

```
result = functions[0]();
```

should result in a non definable behaviour (even abortion of the running program). But it does not. The result is as if the destruction has never happened.

Currently, I can imagine two sources of errors for this behaviour:

1. Destruction does not happen
2. The compiler inlines the content of the array at compile time and therefore, the destruction has no effect.

So far the 3rd party tool never showed the behaviour of not destructing what it is supposed to destruct. Therefore, I have to assume the latter.

How can I prevent the compiler from inlining the content of the functions array?

Comment: The function pointers are `const`, so you are not allowed to change them.

Comment: What mch said. Amusing that you don't get the "expected" UB in one part of the code, because you probably have UB in another.

Comment: Could you post a [MCVE]? Look at the generated assembly code. Use a debugger.

Comment: How exactly does the 3d party too "destroy" the contents of the `functions` array? What happens if you remove the `const` from the declaration?

Comment: You can try removing `const`, and making the array `volatile`. Also of course by just disassembling your call site you will know if the compiler optimized out the array read or not.

Comment: Generally, compilers tend to have a hard time inlining calls through function pointers. But since it is a `const` array, the compiler could possibly have managed it. Easy to find out, just disassemble the optimized code.

Comment: "should result in a non definable behaviour (even abortion of the running program). But it does not. The result is as if the destruction has never happened." => why do you suppose that undefined behavior can't produce something that doesn't crash ? UB is UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler may inline the functions because you declared the array `const` and it isn't `volatile`. So according to the abstract execution model, it may suppose that the array never changes.

To ensure that you may be able to change the array, you'd have to remove the `const`.

To ensure that your compiler takes changes from elsewhere into account you'd have to add `volatile`.

Comment: More precisely, the compiler may assume the array contents do not change because they are **defined** with `const`, not merely declared. If I were passed an array whose elements had a declared type with `const`, it is possible something is changing the elements through a different pointer to them.

Comment: If something is `const volatile`, even defined with them, not just declared, I expect the `volatile` to require the compiler to load on every use, in spite of the `const`, although I do not have a C standard citation at hand.

Comment: No, it makes not much of a difference for const if it is defined and not just declared. The thing is that as long as it isn't volatile, and there is no other function call or so between two accesses, the compiler may assume that nothing has changed. The const is only helping you in that the compiler would not allow you to modify, it doesn't say if it can't change.

Comment: You have added a constraint: That there is no other function call between accesses. The OP does not indicate such a limit applies.

Answer (score 0):

Your error scenario doesn't make much sense to me, but if we ignore that, you can prevent inlining like this:

```
typedef int func_t (void);

volatile func_t* const[] = {f1, f2};
```

This means that the compiler cannot expect the first item of the array to always be `f1`, making optimization impossible. `volatile` forces a read of the function pointer address before calling it, meaning that there must be an address, meaning that inlining is not possible, since inlined functions do not have addresses.